# Deep Copy with Array

Tags: c#, arrays

Why doesn't `ICloneable`'s `Clone` method return a deep copy?

Here is some sample code:

```
class A : ICloneable 
{
    public int x = 2;
    public A(int x)
    {
       this.x = x; 
    }
       
    public A copy()
    {
        A a = new A(this.x);
        return a; 
    }

     public object Clone()
     {
         A a = new A(this.x);
         return a;
     }
}
```

In the `Main` method :

```
A[] Array1 = new A[4] ;
Array1[0] = new A(0);
Array1[1] = new A(1);
Array1[2] = new A(2);
Array1[3] = new A(3);
A[] Array2 = new A[10];
Array. Copy(Array1, Array2, 4); 

Array2[2].x = 11; 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"Index {i} value: {Array1[i].x}");
```

Remembering that I've only changed element index 2 in `Array2`, here is the output from the code above, listing the values in `Array1`:

```
Index 0 value: 0
Index 1 value: 1
Index 2 value: 11
Index 3 value: 3
```

Index 2 in `Array1` has `11` even though I changed it in `Array2` and class `A` implements `ICloneable`!

What then is the benefit of `Array` implementing `ICloneable`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx:

"If sourceArray and destinationArray are both reference-type arrays or are both arrays of type Object, a shallow copy is performed. A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array containing references to the same elements as the original Array. The elements themselves or anything referenced by the elements are not copied"

There may be a better method than this, but one technique you could use is:

```
  A[] array2 = array1.Select (a =>(A)a.Clone()).ToArray();
```

Comment: But important to note in the general case that [implementing `ICloneable` doesn't  guarantee clones will be deep copies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-implementers): "_The ICloneable interface simply requires that your implementation of the Clone() method return a copy of the current object instance. It does not specify whether the cloning operation performs a deep copy, a shallow copy, or something in between._"

Answer (score 2):

Array.Copy copies the values of the array, in this case, references.  There is nothing in the documentation of Array.Copy() that indicates a check for classes that implement IClonable and call Clone() instead.  You will need to loop through the array and call Clone() yourself.

BTW, yes, IClonable kind of sucks.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.Copy()` does not use ICloneable. It simply copies values stored in each cell (which in this case are references to your A objects)

Answer (score 2):

Ani's answer uses [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) thus does not work for C# 2.0, however a same method can be done using the [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array%28v=vs.80%29) class's [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exc45z53%28v=vs.80%29) method:

```
A[] Array2 = Array.ConvertAll(Array1,a => (A)a.Clone());
```