# Why using Cellular Automata with 2d array gives bad results?

Tags: c#, procedural-generation, cellular-automata

I'm trying to make a procedurally generated map/2d_array using Cellular Automata.

I found a good video explaining Cellular automata and followed it.
Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slTEz6555Ts

But for some reason I only get a fully filled 2d array with the same value and not a procedurally generated map like 2d array.
I tried to Debug it and see what's the problem and for some reason this if statement is always false:

```
//check if neighbor is a - and if so add neighbor_wall_count
 if (temp_grid[k, j] == '-')
 {
    neighbor_wall_count++;
 }
```

And I can't find the reason why.
Maybe you could help?

Heres all the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this line string is used for printing
            string line = "";
            //2d array size specifications
            int width = 10;
            int height = 10;
            //density = how much procent will be - in the array when i we make random noise
            int density = 60;
            //create the 2d array
            char[,] grid = new char[width, height];

            //This creates random noise in array or its a function make_noise_grid(density) from video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slTEz6555Ts
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                line = "";
                for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int rand = new Random().Next(1, 100);
                    if(rand > density)
                    {
                        grid[x, y] = '+';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid[x, y] = '-';
                    }
                    line += grid[x, y];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            // This is just a divider to divide random noise map from map with applied with cellulat automata
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

            //This section is the function apply_cellular_automation(grid, count) from video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slTEz6555Ts
            //This first for will determine how much times Cellular Automata will be added
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                //Create a temporary map
                char[,] temp_grid = grid;
                //Go through array
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        //create variable to store neighbor minuses (-)
                        int neighbor_wall_count = 0;
                        //go through neigbors
                        for (int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++)
                        {
                            for(int k = x-1; k <= x+1; k++)
                            {
                                //check if in bounds of array if not just assume its -
                                if (j >= 0 && j < grid.GetLength(1) && k >= 0 && k < grid.GetLength(0))
                                {
                                    //check if this is not the coordinate whose neighbors we are checking
                                    if (j != y && k != x)
                                    {
                                        //check if neighbor is a - and if so add neighbor_wall_count
                                        if (temp_grid[k, j] == '-')
                                        {
                                            neighbor_wall_count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    neighbor_wall_count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //if there are more than 4 neighbors that are - make the coordinate a - and if not make it +
                        if (neighbor_wall_count > 4)
                        {
                            grid[x, y] = '-';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grid[x, y] = '+';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // this is to print the array when we apply Cellular automata.
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                line = "";
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    line += grid[x, y];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result from this:

```
-------+--
++---+-+--
+--++--+-+
--+--+----
-+--+-----
----+-+---
---+--+++-
-+---++--+
+--+-----+
++---+--+-
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-++-+-+-+-
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
-++++++++-
```

Comment: Your two inner loops look like that `for (int j = y-1; j < y+1; j++)`, but think about it, it covers only values `j == y-1` and `j == y`, skipping `j == y+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost 3 years later but i will post this in case this serves to anyone to see a working cellular automata cave system, your fault in your code is the condition in the [k,j] loops of checking if your are in the x and y block, your condition is reversed, this is the correct condition in if: (j != y || k != x)

This is the working code:

```
    //this line string is used for printing
    string line = "";
    //2d array size specifications
    int width = 40;
    int height = 40;
    //density = how much procent will be - in the array when i we make random noise
    int density = 40;
    //create the 2d array
    char[,] grid = new char[width, height];

    //This creates random noise in array or its a function make_noise_grid(density) from video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slTEz6555Ts
    var random = new Random();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        line = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int rand = random.Next(1, 100);
            if (rand > density)
            {
                grid[x, y] = '#'; //wall
            }
            else
            {
                grid[x, y] = '.'; //free space
            }
            line += grid[x, y];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    // This is just a divider to divide random noise map from map with applied with cellulat automata
    Console.WriteLine("\\\\-------------------------------------------------------------------//");

    //This section is the function apply_cellular_automation(grid, count) from video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slTEz6555Ts
    //This first for will determine how much times Cellular Automata will be added
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        //char[,] temp_grid = DeepCopy(width, height, grid);
        char[,] temp_grid = (char[,])grid.Clone();

        //Go through array
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                //create variable to store neighbor minuses (-)
                int neighbor_wall_count = 0;
                //go through neigbors
                for (int k = x - 1; k <= x + 1; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++)
                    {
                        //check if in bounds of array if not just assume its -
                        if (j >= 0 && j < grid.GetLength(1) && k >= 0 && k < grid.GetLength(0))
                        {
                            //check if this is not the coordinate whose neighbors we are checking
                            if (j != y || k != x)
                            {
                                //check if neighbor is a # and if so add neighbor_wall_count
                                if (temp_grid[k, j] == '#')
                                {
                                    neighbor_wall_count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            neighbor_wall_count++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (neighbor_wall_count > 4)
                {
                    grid[x, y] = '#';
                }
                else
                {
                    grid[x, y] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // this is to print the array when we apply Cellular automata.
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        line = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            line += grid[x, y];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

This is the result:

```
    .##..##...######.###########..###..#####
    ....##..#..#.#.#####.#.###.#.#..#..#.###
    ###.###..######.#.##.#...#.#####.###..##
    #.#.#######...##...##.##..#.#..#..##.###
    #######..##.########.#....#.##.###....#.
    ####...#.####..#.#.#.#.###..#..###..##.#
    ###..###..##.....##.###..##.###.#.#.##.#
    ##..##..#.###.#...##..#.##..##.#..#...##
    .###.#.###.####.#..##....#.....##...##.#
    #.##.########......######.##.##.##.##.#.
    .##.##..##.##...##.##.#.#.######..#.##.#
    #.###..##.###..###########...##..#.#.#..
    ...##.#....##..#.##...#...###..#####.###
    ...##.##......#.....####..####...####...
    .##...#.##.#.##..#...###.##...#.#.##...#
    .##.####....#.#####.##.##.#..#######..#.
    ##########...####.##.####.####..#..#.#.#
    ###.##..#.#.#..####.#...####.#.##..#..#.
    #.#.#####.########.###..#...###.#..#..#.
    #..#.####....###.##########..###....#.#.
    ##..#.###.##..#####.##.##.##...#..#.####
    ####.#.#.#.#...###.#.####.##.#...##.####
    ##.#.##.#.#.###..####.####.####.###.#.#.
    ##.#.###.#.#.##.#.#.#.####...#.#...#.###
    .####.###..#..###...#.###.####...#####..
    #.####.###..#..#.######..#.##.#.......#.
    ..#.#..#.#.##.#..#.#..##..#.....#.######
    ...####.###.#.##...#####.#.###.####.....
    #####..##.##..###.###.#.###.##..#...#...
    ###.#..##.##.#.##.##.##...#......#####.#
    .######...##.###.####.#..#.#.####.#.##.#
    #.#...###.####..###.###.####.###.#.###.#
    ##.###..#..#####...####.###.###..##.#.##
    #..##....##.##.#....#.####..##.#..##..##
    .#..#....##.##.#...####..###.####..##.#.
    #..##..#..####.#..#######.###.#..#.###.#
    ####.#.#...#.#..#######.####.####.#.#.##
    .........####..#....#.##.#..##.##.#..#.#
    ###.#.#...#####.###.##..##...####.###.##
    #..##.#...#..####.###..#########.##.###.
    \\-------------------------------------------------------------------//
    #..#####.###############################
    ##...##...###########.#.###.#.##..#.####
    #..########...##.####.#.#.#.#.....#.####
    #######..############......####.###...##
    ############..###.#.#.#....#....#....###
    #######...##....###.#.#....#.#####....##
    ###......####.....##...###...#.#.#....##
    ###...##.#####.....###........#......###
    ###.#.########.....###.##.....#.......##
    #####.########.....###...#..#.##....##.#
    #####.#######.....########..###....##...
    ...###.....##...####.#.#..#######.#.#.##
    ...###.#........#..#####...###...####...
    .....#...............##...##....####...#
    #..#.###.......#....#####..#.#.#.###....
    ####.####....#####...#####.#...#.##....#
    ########......#######..######.#####....#
    ##########.#.#########.#.#.####........#
    ##.#####.#...#########.####..###.......#
    ##..######.###############....#......#.#
    ###..####.....#############...#....#.###
    ###.#.###.#...###############....#.#.###
    ###.#.##.......#####.######.#......#.###
    ###.#####...####.#.#.##########..#####.#
    #########......#.#.#.#####..#.........##
    .####.###.......#....###..##......####.#
    ...####.###..#....#####....##....#.....#
    #.###..#####.#.#..#######.#......#.#...#
    ######.#####..##...#####...#.....###....
    ######...####.########...#.........##...
    ####...#.####.#.######....#...#..#######
    ######.....#####..####.#.##.#####.######
    #........######.....###########...##.###
    #...#......####....############....#.#.#
    #..#......#####....############...####.#
    ###........##.#...######.########..#####
    #.........###......#############.#.#.###
    ###.......####..######..###..#####.#..##
    #.........######...#...####.######.#.###
    ######.#.###############################
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, The For Loops for J & K should be <= instead of <.
The Second issue is that you have to create a deep copy of the map as a reference.
You cant use the same map to write and read from for this, because the previous steps within one iteration might change the outcome of another cell within a iteration. Debug the Steps one by one to see this.
Basically, have one Array to Read the Cell State, then another to write the new Cell state.
Then after the Iteration is done the Read Cells can be set the same to the write Cells

Comment: Using <= helped a bit, but still I get only few minuses. And I create the temp_grid as a copy and read from it and change the main grid. Or am I doing something wrong with my temp_grid?

Comment: Actually temp_grid = temp doesnt copy the grid. What you are looking for is a deep copy. I didnt see that at first, but I think if you deep copy it it should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464635/deep-copy-with-array this has some good examples

Comment: I did it like this: char[,] temp_grid = grid.Clone() as char[,]; , but still same