# Variable value changing with the change of array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

```
PremiumBill x = list.OrderBy(j => j.PostingDate).FirstOrDefault(j => j.PostingDate >= input.PostingDate);
```

Hello I'm trying to save a value from the array in a variable to preserve it while the array is changing but the variable's value is changing with its change.
I have tried

```
PremiumBill[] temporaryList = (PremiumBill[])List.ToArray().Clone();

PremiumBill x = temporaryList.OrderBy(j => j.PostingDate).FirstOrDefault(j => j.PostingDate >= input.PostingDate);
```

I tried copy to and got the same thing

Comment: In C#, you work with references to the objects. When you clone your array, you actually clone pointers too, so they eventually point to the same objects. You need to implement `Clone` and actually clone your object, e.g. `PremiumBill x = temporaryList.OrderBy(...).FirstOrDefault(...).Clone()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a deep-copy of the array. Currently, what you have is a shallow copy where both arrays are pointing to the same references.

Below is an example of a deep copy using `ICloneable` interface. There are different ways to perform a deep copy and what I usually prefer is simply serializing and deserializing using JSON. This method works for serializeable objects but if ever you encounter an exception, use the `ICloneable` interface instead. You may refer to this question [Deep Copy with Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464635/6138713).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo[] foos = new Foo[] 
        { 
            new Foo() { Bar = 1 } ,
            new Foo() { Bar = 2 } ,
            new Foo() { Bar = 3 } ,
        };
        
        Foo[] tempFoos = foos.Select(r => (Foo)r.Clone()).ToArray();
        
        foos[0].Bar = 5;
        
        Foo foo1 = tempFoos[0];
        
        Console.WriteLine(foo1.Bar); // outputs 1
    }
}

class Foo : ICloneable
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Foo() { Bar = this.Bar };
    }
}
```

Posted an answer as it makes more sense to do so with an example.